# Events are fired but dont change UI

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am relatively new to Events and I'm trying to understand why my code wont work properly. I want to trigger an event when an action is started, to set the label text to "started" and when the method finished, the label would say "finished". Pretty basic so far. Both Events are being triggered but in the StartEvent, the UI-Label is not being updated, although i Set a breakpoint at `EventsClassOnStartedWorkEvent`. The line is kind of being executed but the Label is not being changed. I also tried a longer execution time in `DoWork()`. After the loop finished, the `FinishedWorkEvent` properly changes the UI-Label.

What i have tried: Subscribe to the events in the `MainWindow` Constructor.

Thanks in Advance.

```
using EventsNamespace;
using System;

namespace DLL
{
    class EventsClass
    {
        public event TestEventEventHandler FinishedWorkEvent;
        public event TestEventEventHandler StartedWorkEvent;

        public void DoWork()
        {
            StartedWorkEvent(this,new UIEventArgs("started"));



            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
            }


            FinishedWorkEvent(this, new UIEventArgs("Finished"));


        }

    }
}

namespace EventsNamespace
{
    public delegate void TestEventEventHandler(object sender, UIEventArgs e);

    public class UIEventArgs : EventArgs
    {

        public string Result { get; set; }

        public UIEventArgs(string result)
        {
            Result = result;
        }

    }
```

---

```
using DLL;
using EventsNamespace;
using System.Windows;

namespace EventsTestUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private EventsClass eventsClass;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            eventsClass = new EventsClass();
        }

        private void EventsClassOnFinishedWorkEvent(object sender, UIEventArgs e)
        {
            ResultLabel.Content = e.Result;
        }

        private void EventsClassOnStartedWorkEvent(object sender, UIEventArgs e)
        {
            ResultLabel.Content = e.Result;
        }


        private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            eventsClass.StartedWorkEvent += EventsClassOnStartedWorkEvent;
            eventsClass.FinishedWorkEvent += EventsClassOnFinishedWorkEvent;
            eventsClass.DoWork();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Angevil I now have made ```DoWork()``` ```async``` and it works. I made it by using: ```await Task.Run( ()=> {  //while loop in here]);```  and before / after the task i fire the events. That's what you mean right?

Comment: try `Dispatcher.Invoke( () =>ResultLabel.Content = e.Result );` 
see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code flow in a console app, and the events are fired (you may test by adding `Console.WriteLine()` in your event handlers).
So I am pretty sure that the problem here are not the events themselves.

If my memory is correct, in WPF you only have 1 thread to refresh the UI, and it is the same thread that handles user-induced events, such as a click on that start button.

Which means that the events are probably fired, and the content of the label is changed, but the UI is not refreshed until the thread has finished `DoWork()` so you won't see any change on your UI before that.

One way to correct this would be to call `DoWork` asynchronously => another thread takes care of doing the work, and the UI thread is released to refresh the UI when needed.